# Unix - remove file with pound signs around it

Tags: unix, emacs

I am using SSH to another terminal with very limited disk space. upon typing ls I see a file called #korpus.txt#. I suspect this file is an emacs buffer, but upon running emacs and trying to kill it with C-x k bufname RET, it isn't found. How can I remove #korpus.txt#?

Comment: what about "rm #korpus.txt#" ? The pound sign is nothing magical, just another character.

Comment: I get rm: `missing operand`

Comment: The `#` needs to be escaped. `rm \#korpus.txt\#` is what you need to do. @WillP.'s answer did not mention this.

Answer (score 0):

`rm '#korpus.txt#'` solved the problem. The quote marks are necessary for escaping the #. Did not try Class Stackers solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some other methods to delete oddly-named files, though less optimal than those previously described, can get you by in a pinch:

- Careful use of wildcards:

  `rm -i ?korpus.txt?`
- Try using filename completion.  In bash:

  `rm #`<kbd>tab</kbd> changed to `rm \#korpus.txt#`
- Try using a different shell just for the task.

  `/bin/tcsh` had no issue with `rm #korpus.txt#`

Answer (score 0):

Since you added tag `emacs`, here is the Emacs way to do it:

In [**Dired**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) (`C-x d`):

1. Type **`#`** to flag all such files for deletion (mark `D`).
2. Then type **`x`** to delete them all.